# How to solve this 2-D integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How to solve 
$$I=\int_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dxdy}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)}$$

I've tried using the diffeomorphism $(x,y)=(u,v/u)$ from $\text{int}\{(u,v)\mid 0\le u\le 1,0\le v\le u\}$ to $\text{int}[0,1]^2$, but since the Jaccobian determinant becomes unbounded at the boundary, the transformation leads to an improper integral, which I think makes it invalid.

If I integrate directly over the original domain, the result will be too complicated to calculate.

I can't come up with another diffeomorphism. Is there another method to go on?

Comment: Have you tried integrating over $y$ first? I haven't tried the calculation, but it seems you can integrate a natural log by using integration by parts.

Comment: @JohnMolokach yes I have. That is mentioned in my post as "integrate over the original domain". I have produced log but to no avail

Comment: possible to use a contour with Residue Theorem?

Comment: @JohnMolokach Is it? Sorry I'm not familiar with complex analysis.

Comment: Nvm. There are no singularities in your region, so Theorem does not apply.

Comment: Your diffeomorphism approach can be adapted by cutting off a piece of the domain and then shrinking this piece away. Since your original integrand is perfectly nice, you can do that back in $(x,y)$ space, compute the partial integral in $(u,v)$ space, and then take the limit in $(x,y)$ space.

Comment: Alternately, John Molokach's approach reduces your problem to $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)} dx$. This might be approachable by series methods, though I seem to have had a problem when I tried to do so myself.

Comment: @Ian I don't think it's easy to justify that diffeomorphism, since the Jacobian determinant is unbounded at the boundary (to be exact, which makes the diffeomorphism probably invalid is that the determinant is unbounded over the "interior domain"). ( I don't think I can cut off what is more than the boundary set (of Lebesgue measure zero))

Comment: Would $(u,v) \mapsto (u,v/u)$ be a diffeomorphism from $\{ (u,v/u) : u \in [\delta,1],v \in [0,u] \}$ to a subset of the square? As $\delta \to 0^+$, does it fill out the volume of the square? If so, then that will work.

Comment: @Ian Yeah this is cool. but I am still at a loss how to approach integrating $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x^2)}$ itself

Comment: My best idea there was term-by-term integration using the Cauchy product: replace $\ln(1+x)$ with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2k}$, then multiply the series and try to integrate. I think you also need a "cutoff" approach to make this work, i.e. I think you will need to only integrate over $[0,1-\delta]$ and then send $\delta \to 0^+$, in order to avoid convergence issues. But I elected not to leave that answer up because I couldn't work out the convergence/algebra issues at this time.

Comment: @Ian I've proceeded a bit using your series method. But the integral limits involving $\delta$ will make the terms ugly and impossible to sum up

Comment: You can write $b$ instead of $1-\delta$ and send $b \to 1^-$, if it's any nicer that way. I'm just not sure that you can pass the integration limit through the several limits which are in the way, so I wanted to be careful by putting it on the outside.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the $x$ integral has no elementary antiderivative, so I think something like this series method might be essential.

Comment: It is not: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$ has a continuous extension to $x=0$ (the value is $1$, i.e. the derivative of $\ln$ at $1$).

Comment: @Ian Fair point, you're right. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the slickest way, but at least it works. First decompose into partial fractions with respect to $x$:
$$
\frac{1}{(1+xy)(1+x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+y^2} \left( \frac{y^2}{1+xy} + \frac{1-xy}{1+x^2} \right)
.
$$
Rewrite this (using $y^2=(1+y^2)-1$ as)
$$
\frac{1}{1+xy}
- \frac{1}{(1+xy)(1+y^2)}
+ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+y^2}
- \frac{x}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{y}{1+y^2}
.
$$
The last two terms are easy to integrate over the square, since $x$ and $y$ separate.

The integral of the second term equals the integral that we're trying to compute (call it $I$), by symmetry.

The integral of the first term is trickier, but we can expand $(1+xy)^{-1}=1 - x y  + x^2 y^2 - x^3 y^3 + \dotsb$, which upon termwise integration gives the known series $1-1/2^2+1/3^2-1/4^2+\dotsb = \pi^2/12$. One could probably also get this in the same way as the integral of $(1-xy)^{-1}$ over the unit square is computed in Chapter 8 of *Proofs from THE BOOK* by Aigner & Ziegler, namely by setting $x=u-v$ and $y=u+v$.

All combined, we get
$$
I = \frac{\pi^2}{12} - I + \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\ln 2}{2} \right)^2
,
$$
so
$$
I=\frac{7 \pi^2}{96} - \frac{\ln^2 2}{8}
.
$$

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you, sir!